# Reassembling Raid 10 in Ubuntu from the initramfs menu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, mdadm, initramfs

My raid 10 - used for / - has failed for my Ubuntu box.

I replaced the bad disk and I am trying to reassemble the raid from the initramfs menu. I have tried starting the degraded Raid and using the recovery startup option

When I run the mdadm --assemble /dev/md1  (devices) command it tell me that the first devices is busy or not accessible. However I can run mdadm --examine on the device in question

any ideas?

Comment: Please include the output of 'mdadm --detail /dev/md1'.  Also, could it be that the array was assembled successfully, but wasn't started?  If that happened, 'mdadm --run /dev/md1' may get the array online in degraded mode.

Comment: The output is /dev/md1 does not appear to be active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't figured this out already, you would almost certainly be better off booting off a livecd and repairing things.  Initramfs provides a very limited environment.  It is much easier to repair things from more complete system.